# Конвертируем html в изображение.

Tags: php

Прошу вашей помощи в поиске php библиотеки для конвертирование html + css в изображение pgn,jpg,gif.

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь](http://hashcode.ru/questions/100600/автоматизация-скриншотов-веб-страниц). Может быть что-нибудь найдете полезное.

Comment: ещё 15 способов, правда не php: http://mashable.com/2007/08/24/web-screenshots/

Comment: @Александр Фисенко - есть доступ к `shell_exec`?

Comment: Доступ к shell_exet Есть вот нашел интересный вариант  http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/. если есть что то похожие с удовольствием посмотрю

Comment: Вам нужно изображение всей страницы (т.е. от самого верха до самого низа) или ее части?

Comment: Можно сказать да

Answer (score 3):

[Вот пример конвертации Html => PDF => PNG / JPEG](http://buffernow.com/html-to-image-php-script/)

```
$html_content = '<p>Hello World</p>';

$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4');
$html2pdf->writeHTML($html_content);
$file = $html2pdf->Output('temp.pdf','F');

$im = new imagick('temp.pdf');
$im->setImageFormat( "jpg" );
$img_name = time().'.jpg';
$im->setSize(800,600);
$im->writeImage($img_name);
$im->clear();
$im->destroy();
```

По началу не забудьте подключить библиотеку HTML2PDF или [mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php?page=Download)